# Why doesn't callback get called when the app is in background?

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, titanium, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a titanium app that needs to display a [Banner Message](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Local+Notifications) under iOS when a push notification comes in. Therefore I used the following code to register on incoming push notifications:

```
var callbacks = {
    types: [
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND,
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT
    ],
    success:function(e){
        console.log("success");
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log("error");
    },
    callback: function(e){
        console.log("new push notification")
        //code for displaying banner message would go here!
    }
};

if(Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings){ //iOS 8 +
    function onUserNotificationSettings(){
        delete callbacks.types;
        Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications(callbacks);
        Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener("usernotificationsettings",onUserNotificationSettings);
    }
    Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener("usernotificationsettings",onUserNotificationSettings)
    Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings(callbacks)
}else{ //up to iOS 7
    Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications(callbacks)
}
```

But the callback function does not get called when the app is in background. So, I also can't display the banner message there, since the code won't get executed.

What could be the reason why the callback does not get called when the app is in background? When it is in foreground, it works perfectly. Is it normal? If yes, where else would I put my code to display the banner message?

I'm using SDK version 3.4.0 on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.1

Please note that sending the banner text through the apn-payload is not the solution. There are other usecases. For example, when the server needs to tell the client that there is new content to sync, where the user does not even need to get notified for. The client should just download the new content in background just when the notification arrives.

Comment: The callback will not be trigger if the app is in background. If you want to execute some codes when the app is in background, you need to run background services in iOS

Comment: @Anand according to [this](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService) a background service can run no longer than 10 minutes after the app has been terminated. What about after that? Additionally, what would I do in the background service? Polling all X seconds? :/

Comment: The iOS banner will display whatever texts that you send through push notifications. Its not based on the callback. When you send a push notification, it should contain a payload. the payload will be displayed there. This banner will not be displayed if you have opened your application and hence I think in callback you are trying to display a banner that is created by you. right?

Comment: @Anand I don't want to send the message that should be displayed to the user from the server because of many reasons (language, the server does not know it, etc.), also I don't want to set the amount of notifications (badge) from the server, because only the client knows how many unread notifications he has. The server server just tells the client that there are new messages. Additionally, the server tells the client that there is some new stuff he should download, for example profile information that was changed on another logged in client. For this I need to get the callback called.

Comment: Why the downvote btw? This is a really good question that the Titanium Docs do not answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how to do it!
The callback **will** get called when the app is in background. All I had to do for it was to add the following to my `tiapp.xml` in `ti:app/ios/plist/dict`:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

After that, everything works fine!

Comment: This is what I told you in my answer. Why did you answer it again and accept yours?

Comment: @Mike Gottlieb You have changed your answer. It did not tell the correct answer before. You can have the bounty if you want, it'd be wasted otherwise ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to register for the remote-notification background mode. This will wake up your app and give you execution time when you send the notifications.

For the record this is in the Appcelerator docs [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services-section-37539664_iOSBackgroundServices-SettingApplicationPermissions.1)

Comment: I've tried to listen to this event. But it also only got called after I've added the code from my answer to tiapp.xml.

Comment: Now this answer is also correct. I'll keep my answer accepted, since it outright provides the solution, while in your answer, I'll have to visit a link and read it by myself.